# Wordpress Category API

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I have this code:

```
public static function category($id = null) {
    $fields = ['id'=>'cat_ID','slug'=>'slug','title'=>'name','description'=>'description','count'=>'count'];
    // All categories
    $categories = get_categories([
        'orderby'=>'id',
        'order'=>'ASC'
    ]);
    // Get all categories
    if($id === null) {
        return sanitize( $categories, $fields);
    // Get category by its ID or Slug
    } else {
        if( is_numeric($id) ) {
            return sanitize( find($categories, 'cat_ID', $id), $fields); // By ID
        } else {
            return sanitize( find($categories, 'slug', $id), $fields);// By Slug
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to get the category by id (like integer number), but it doesn't work.

Comment: why u don't use this <?php print_r(get_category(1)); ?>

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function wordpress already have

```
<?php 
$cats = get_category(1/*change the number with your cats id*/);
echo $cats->term_id; //get the cats id
echo $cats->name; //get the cats title
echo $cats->slug; //get the cats slug
echo $cats->description; //get the cats description
echo $cats->category_count; //get the cats count
?>
```